# Magento SOAP-ERROR, wrong API URL

Tags: php, magento, soap, wsdl, magento-1.7

I'm having problems with the SOAP API in Magento 1.7.0.2

this is the error:

```
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 
'http://USRNM:PSWRD@https://www.example.com/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1' :
failed to load external entity 
"http://USRNM:PSWRD@https://www.example.com/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1"
```

I don't know why it appends a random `USRNM:PSWRD` before the actual link... doing this when link visited it redirects to "*https//*" without the ":" before "//"

edit: actually the user/pass added is the one of APC

I've tried to add: `IP ADDRESS example.com` in `/etc/hosts` but it doesn't work...

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this had nothing to do with Magento

Comment: why do you say that? @RobbieAverill

Answer (score 0):

Use the below for solution:

SOAP :

http://magentohost/api/?wsdl

http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl

http://magentohost/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

XML-RPC :

http://magentohost/api/xmlrpc/